# Which came first. The Material World or Spirit World

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

I am wondering how the spirit world came into existence if anyone knows and which came first? The Material World or the Spirit World. Since there are some spirits like Raava or Vaatu or the Moon and Ocean Spirits that could have created both worlds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wikia both worlds were one until Avatar Wan closed the spirit portals and the two worlds became separate.